# How to join two names to create one function name

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my template I'm trying to dynamically define the path helper inside:

```
<%= link "Edit", to: @options[:resource]_path(@options[:conn], :edit, @options[:resource]) %>
```

So, I would like to use `@options[:resource]` to prepend the resource name and create the correct path helper, like: `post_path(@conn, :edit, post)`

As this is a function name and not a string all methods I've tried (`#{}, <>, ++`) don't work.

Comment: What's the value of `@options[:resource]`? Is it a String, Atom, or Struct?

Comment: Well...I'm passing just `post`, not a string, atom or struct...

Comment: Can you add the code for the controller action which calls this template?

Comment: After your first comment I just realized that it would be much easier if I'd use a string instead and change some logic in the way I'm handling this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to dynamically call the function, [`Kernel#apply/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3) should help here:

```
<%= link "Edit", to: apply(
       __MODULE__,
       :"#{@options[:resource]}_path",
       [@options[:conn], :edit, @options[:resource]]
    ) %>
```

Comment: `apply/2` only works for anonymous functions. Also, I don't think `@options[:resource]` is a string or atom or `apply/3` would work with `MyApp.Router` as the first argument.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, fixed to mention `apply/3`. OP stated that the expected result is “like `post_path(...`,” that’s why I expect a string/atom there. In any case this string/atom should be easily retrievable from whatever `@options[:resource]` is.